CW-complex that is simply connected and with the cohomology ring as a wedge of spheres
I know that if the reduced (co)homology of a simply connected CW complex is concentrated in one dimension and it is free then it is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres, see this question. One can prove this with the Hurewicz theorem and Whitehead theorem.
Q: If the cohomology ring of a CW-complex $X$ is that of a wedge of spheres of several dimensions and it is simply connected, is it homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres?
I know that homology is not enough, for example $S^2\times S^2$ is not homotopic to $S^2\vee S^2\vee S^4$, but that fails because of the cohomology ring! And in the other case I cannot use the Hurewicz theorem.
Sorry if this is trivial, I cannot come up with a counterexample.

Consider the suspension $\Sigma\mathbb{CP}^2$. Cup products are always trivial in a suspension, so this space has the same cohomology ring as $S^3\vee S^5$ (with any coefficients).  However, it is not homotopy equivalent to $S^3\vee S^5$, since with mod $2$ coefficients the Steenrod square $Sq^2$ sends the nonzero class in $H^3$ to the nonzero class in $H^5$.
(More generally, Steenrod operations are a good source of examples like this, since they are preserved by suspension, whereas suspension kills the cup product structure.)
